# Test If a PC is Logged in Over a Network

Tags: perl, autoit

Is there any way using Perl, PS Tools, or Autoit, to test a PC, over my network, to see if it is powered on and logged in?

For example:

- Script begins
- Script tests pc to see if it is powered on and logged in as a user
- Script runs a task on that pc

A Plus:

- Return 0 if the pc is not logged in and/or powered off
- Return the user name of who ever is logged in.

Comment: Logged in to what? A user is currently logged in? What platform/OS?

Comment: For example script tests a pc to see if its logged in as a user and returns either the users name or 0 if the PC is powered off or not logged in.

Comment: Wiggle the mouse.  If nothing happens, it’s probably dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TASKLIST /S hostname /U username
TASKLIST /S hostname /U domain\username
```

will show you all the tasks that a user is running on a machine. If it returns an error or no output, then the user is not logged on. Otherwise, you parse the program list and decide for yourself whether the programs indicate that the user is logged on, or there are just some tasks running in the background on his/her behalf.

Comment: Thanks, that was a major help to tell me if the pc is powered on or off however, it's still returning true if a user is not logged in. How would I check to see if a specific user is logged on and if the screensaver is running or not? Thanks.

Comment: See if the name of the screensaver program is in the TASKLIST output?

Comment: When the screensaver is running the process will be called "name of screensaver".scr , now I I am just going to do a FileWriteLine("pslistLog.txt", ShellExecuteWait("pslist", "\\"name of the test PC" -u -p")) and parse pslistLog for ".scr" since PSlist cannot parse the process names.